# Array sorting in java

Tags: java

please explain the j+1

In sorting program i saw this line.please explain
code is here

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
       for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++)
       {
                if(numbers[i] > numbers[j + 1])
                {
                            tempVar = numbers [j + 1];
                            numbers [j + 1]= numbers [i];
                            numbers [i] = tempVar;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: `j+1` stands for the adjacent element to `j` in the array

Comment: The `j+1` is almost certainly a mistake as it will lead to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the last iteration of the inner loop.

Comment: Change `j < numbers.length` with this `j < numbers.length - i`. and search for bubble sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code goes through an array and checks if the number at `array[i]` is greater than the number at `array[i + 1]` meaning number number to the right of `array[i]`. Then it swaps them. This is a sorting algorithm called `Bubble sort`. So if there is an array `( 3 2 1 )` the loop would go through, see that `3 > 2`, swap 3 and 2 then see that `2 > 1` and swap 2 and 1. The array isn't fully sorted yet, but with enough passes it will be. That is the idea behind `Bubble sort`

Step by step example:

> Lets say we have an array ( 5 1 4 2 8 ) and we want to use bubble sort to sort it.

```
First Pass:
( 5 1 4 2 8 ) to ( 1 5 4 2 8 ), Here, algorithm compares the first two elements, and swaps since 5 > 1.
( 1 5 4 2 8 ) to ( 1 4 5 2 8 ), Swap since 5 > 4
( 1 4 5 2 8 ) to ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Swap since 5 > 2
( 1 4 2 5 8 ) to ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Now, since these elements are already in order (8 > 5), algorithm does not swap them.
Second Pass:
( 1 4 2 5 8 ) to ( 1 4 2 5 8 ), Already in order -> no swap
( 1 4 2 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Swap since 4 > 2
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Already in order -> no swap
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Already in order -> no swap
Now, the array is already sorted, but our algorithm does not know if it is  
completed. The algorithm needs one whole pass without any swap to know it is sorted.
Third Pass:
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Already in order -> no swap
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Already in order -> no swap
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Already in order -> no swap
( 1 2 4 5 8 ) to ( 1 2 4 5 8 ), Already in order -> no swap

Now we see that no swaps have been made and this means that the array is completely sorted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
```

our first index, allows us to have a starting point for each iteration

```
{
   for(int j = i+1; j < numbers.length; j++)
```

our second index, allows us to not make redundant swaps and runs the faster without error

```
{
            if(numbers[i] > numbers[j])
```

is i greater than j? if yes

```
            {
                        tempVar = numbers [j];
```

set tempVar to have the same value as the element of numbers at j

```
                        numbers [j]= numbers [i];
```

swaps the values, tempVar stored the backup prior to this statement. The element of numbers at j is overwritten

```
                        numbers [i] = tempVar;
```

swaps the values, tempVar is used to overwrite the element of numbers at i

```
            }

    }
}
```

Use this resource to boost your knowledge: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html